# Restrict file size using

Tags: vb.net, zip, compression, size

I have to create a sub routine using VB.Net that compress some files into a "file.zip" file, but the problem is that this "file.zip" MUST have the maximum size of 2 MB.
I don't know how to do it, even if it's possible.
It would be nice if someone has some example to show me.

Comment: Hi. This isn't really the right format for a question on this forum. You need to try and then ask a specific question if you cannot make it work, ideally showing code that provides a minimally working example.

Comment: Oh ! I see. I didn't knew it. Thanks for the tip, Brick :P

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this in the general case.  For example if you have a 2GB movie file, no lossless compression algorithm will ever get it to 2MB.

One solution is to "chunk" your ZIP file.  That is, divide it into parts that are individually no more than 2MB.  7-Zip has support for this.  You can use their [.NET API](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) from VB.Net.  I'm not sure whether the API provides direct support for chunking.  If not, you can start 7-Zip from your program using `Process.Start()`.

Comment: I'm not trying to compress 2GB into 2MB hahahah
Basically, i have to insert files into this "file.zip" file, by using "AddToArchive(zip, "C:\Transfer-PI\TransferContracts\" + strListadeContratos(i) + ".pdf")" until it reaches 2 MB and the loop stops.

Comment: Your only option then is to add a file, check the archive size, add another file, etc.  Note that adding a file increases the archive by the compressed size of the data itself, plus the additional space needed in the file header to record that file.

Comment: Eric, I think this is my only option then. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Note that you can still use the "chunk" solution by externally running 7-zip.  You use the command line option `-v2m` to make 2mb chunks from your input files.  With that type of archive though you need all of the files together to decompress them.